# How to I obtain the value of the environment variables?

Tags: java, linux, environment-variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Access shell environment variables Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959521/access-shell-environment-variables-java)

I've created a stand-alone java application in linux.

How can I obtain the value of the environment variables (e.g. assigned in the `.bashrc` file).

Comment: duplicate ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959521/access-shell-environment-variables-java ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For obtaining only one System Variable use the following code:

```
 String sysEnvStr = System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");
```

If it returns `null` then make changes in your `.bashrc` file. Try exporting that particular variable.

Comment: Hi, How to create new Variable and using it ? I try: export MY_VAR=xyz but  System.getenv("MY_VAR") still null ?

Answer (score 6):

See [this howto:](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0466.html)

```
// just one
System.out.println("PATH = " + System.getenv("PATH"));

// all of them
Map env = System.getenv();
for (Iterator it=env.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
   Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
   System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: No, getenv was deprecated and then even removed in some dark times of Java, which was a really big stupidity. It has been reinstated in 1.5.

Comment: Yeap, I don't see it as deprecated: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv()

Comment: I want a few specific paths. Not all the paths. Suppose I want only  the path of "NS" then what changes should I do in the above code?

Comment: this what is listed under the comment "just one". `String NS = System.getenv("NS");`

Comment: @Antrromet: Are you sure you understand enviornment variables in general? You want a specific path of what?

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you:

```
$cat Env.java 
class Env { 
  public static void main( String ... args ) {
    for( Object o : System.getenv().entrySet()  ){
      System.out.println( o );
    }
  }
}
$java Env
TERM=xterm
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
SESSION_MANAGER=local/oreyes-laptop:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2341,unix/oreyes-laptop:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2341
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
GDMSESSION=gnome
XDG_SESSION_COOKIE=2604d05dc122db9b636d41744aeeb7a2-1296882161.129722-1315567412
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/gnome.mandatory.path
PS1=$
NLSPATH=/usr/dt/lib/nls/msg/%L/%N.cat
GDM_KEYBOARD_LAYOUT=latam
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-gnome:/etc/xdg
XAUTHORITY=/var/run/gdm/auth-for-oreyes-5QyKYh/database
GDM_LANG=en_US.utf8
USERNAME=oreyes
GTK_MODULES=canberra-gtk-module
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-DqJ9Sg
SHLVL=1
SPEECHD_PORT=7560
XFILESEARCHPATH=/usr/dt/app-defaults/%L/Dt
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
LOGNAME=oreyes
WINDOWID=79691780
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/seahorse-vkmfjC/S.gpg-agent:2385:1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/keyring-DqJ9Sg/ssh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/../lib/i386
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-15CfDJRFNg,guid=6ebfc2e2421576b21ec0d2284d4cd9f2
SHELL=/bin/bash
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=2323
GOARCH=386
DESKTOP_SESSION=gnome
DISPLAY=:0.0
USER=oreyes
HOME=/home/oreyes
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/gnome.default.path
```

Comment: I want a few specific paths. Not all the paths. What changes should I do in the above code?

Comment: @Antrromet You should have asked that in first place, not the  *"value of the environment variables (e.g. assigned in the .bashrc file)"*  Harshit's answer is correct.