# System.getenv() does not list all the environment variables

Tags: java, variables, system, environment

I have noticed that some of my environment variables are not being picked up by the JVM.

In my `.bash_profile` I defined the following:

```
IO_HOME='some_value'
export IO_HOME
```

and by doing in shell:

```
echo $IO_HOME
```

I get the correct result.

But neither `System.getProperties()` nor `System.getenv()` is showing this variable being set. I tried both Java 6 and Java 7.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access shell environment variables Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959521/access-shell-environment-variables-java)

Comment: @MaLLinok are you launching your java application from a bash shell?

Comment: To test whether it's a Bash issue or a Java issue, you can first run `env | grep ^IO_HOME=` to see whether `env` sees this variable (if it does, then this is a Java issue, not a Bash issue), and then run `env IO_HOME='some_value' java your_java_program` to see whether your Java program sees this variable (if it does, then this is a Bash issue, not a Java issue). If these give contradictory results, then the problem is probably somewhere in between: it's probably in how you're running the Java program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exporting environment to spawned processes is pretty stable; if `System.getenv()` is not including a variable then it is because it is not in the environment. A couple of things to check, both relating to how the process is started:

- Are you starting the java process from an environment where the variable is exported? For example, if it is in your .bash_profile and you are executing the java program from a menu or desktop then  you have to log out and log in after adding it in .bash_profile for your desktop to see the variable.
- Is the variable explicitly removed from environment for the process? [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) allows this, as do most of all APIs that spawn processes.

One thing to try is to start the process from command line shell, after ensuring the variable is exported in that shell.

Comment: Since I first set this env variable (a year and a half ago) I never logged out. I assumed that switching off and on my Mac would do that automatically. Seems it does not!

Answer (score 3):

From Windows, I recently saw some crazy behaviour where IntelliJ refused to show all env vars from `System.getenv()` after setting either user or system env vars.  The trick was to launch IntelliJ from a DOS box.  For Windows users: Maybe a reboot (or logoff/logon) will fix the issue.