# Java program not able to pick up environment variables mac

Tags: java, macos, environment-variables, osx-mavericks

Ive looked at several related links such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748367/system-getenv-does-not-list-all-the-environment-variables) but my java program cant seem to pick up an environment variable defined in `/.bashrc`, `/.bash_profile`

Here's my `bash_profile` (bashrc is the same)

```
export JBOSS_HOME=/Applications/whp-jboss-cluster-5
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/
export FDP_HOME=/Users/kodeseeker/Project/git_intuit/
export TOMCAT_HOME=/Library/Tomcat/
export GIT_HOME=/Users/kodeseeker/Project/git_intuit
export MULE_HOME=/usr/local/mule/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.6.0-M2



echo $MULE_HOME returns 
/usr/local/mule/mule-enterprise-standalone-3.6.0-M2 as well.
```

But printing

```
 Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(
                              envName + " "+ 
                              env.get(envName));
        }
        System.out.println("****");
        System.out.println(env.get("MULE_HOME"));// returns null.
```

Both use the same shell
Shell in eclipse from output :

```
SHELL /bin/bash
APP_ICON_12441 ../Resources/Eclipse.icns
TMPDIR /var/folders/jc/bpc8py6s47jftq8mny923n4r5jfsj2/T/

echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

I've tried logging out, restarting the terminal etc. but with no avail. Any insight or links would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked whether the variable is available in the shell that you're running this from? What does `echo $MULE_HOME` print?

Comment: Yup. Same shell .  Should have added that as well.

Comment: You are running the code from JBoss right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` won't be taken in consideration when eclipse start the program as these files are designed for settings used by interactive shells.

To make your variable visible to eclipse, navigate to

> Run -> Run Configuration

Select the tab Environment, and add your variable.

Another way would consist of creating a file (or edit if it already exists) `/etc/launchd.conf` and set the variable in this file for example :

```
setenv MY_VARIABLE MY_VALUE
```

Don't forget to reboot.

Note that this is for OSX (OP's OS), but for normal Linux, you can edit `/etc/environment`