# How Do I check PATH and CLASSPATH environment variables from java?

Tags: java, path, get, classpath, environment-variables

I am making a java program to read an audio.wav file with JMF.I have to set path from cmd every time my computer restarts like this

```
    set CLASSPATH=%WINDIR%\java\classes\jmf.jar;%WINDIR%\java\classes\sound.jar;.;%CLASSPATH%
```

and

```
    set PATH=%WINDIR%\System32;%PATH%
```

otherwise the program will compile but not run
I wanted to do it through

```
    System.setProperty(key,value);
```

I don't know cmd commands,so in order to check the value of CLASSPATH and PATH after setting it through cmd I tried

```
    public void checkProperty (){
    System.setProperty("temporaryvar","blahblah");
    System.out.println(""+System.getProperty("temporaryvar"));//prints out blahblah
    System.out.println(""+System.getProperty("CLASSPATH"));//prints out null
    System.out.println(""+System.getProperty("PATH"));//prints out null
    }
```

I get it printed out as

```
    blahblah
    null
    null
```

What's the reason I am getting the value of variable I set from the program back but not the one I set from the cmd?Is this the right approach?I need to set both these paths from java..plz help

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959521/access-shell-environment-variables-in-java

Comment: @Andremoniy thanks for redirecting me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `CLASSPATH` and `PATH` are environment variables, not Java System Properties. System properties can be passed to your java process using `-Dkey=value`.

Try using [System.getenv()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)) instead.

Comment: Please change it to getenv, I want to copy and paste without thinking :).

Answer (score 26):

Use `System.getenv` instead of `System.getProperty`. Note that you can also get the effective classpath for the current Java process with:

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

And that this value can, and in most cases will, be different from whatever your `CLASSPATH` environment variable is setup to be.

Comment: Did you mean the reverse of your opening sentence? Should it be: “Use `System.getProperty` instead of `System.getenv`. ”? Plus it would be helpful if you expanded with a bit more explanation.